# Interpreting the solutions $v_{n}$ of the equation $16/x+\log(1+2/x+4\log(4/x))=\log(2n)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory

In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.7209.pdf Proposition 4.5 (Page 10), a fundamental component of this proposition is the solution $v_{n}$ of the equation $$16/x + \log(1+2/x+4\log(4/x))=\log(2n)\; (*)$$ that is smaller than $1$ for chosen $n$.

The choice of equation $(*)$ does not seem intuitive to me, and I have no idea how $v_{n}$ varies with $n$. Can anyone give me an intution to the solutions of the equation $(*)$?

Comment: It is possible that I did misunderstand the question. What I gave you are just the solutions of the equation $(*)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look for the zero of function $$f_n(x)=\frac{16}{x}+\log \left(1+\frac{2}{x}+4 \log\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)\right)-\log (2 n)$$, because of the logarithm, we first need that
$$1+\frac{2}{x}+4 \log\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)>0\implies x <\frac{1}{2 W\left(\frac{1}{8 \sqrt[4]{e}}\right)}=5.61448$$ $W(.)$ being Lambert function.

Computing the solution using Newton method with $x_0=5$ does not make any problem.

Some numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 1 &  5.47745 \\
 2 &  5.36034 \\
 3 &  5.25839 \\
 4 &  5.16836 \\
 5 &  5.08791 \\
 6 &  5.01533 \\
 7 &  4.94932 \\
 8 &  4.88886 \\
 9 &  4.83316 \\
 10 &  4.78157 \\
 20 &  4.41029 \\
 30 &  4.17863 \\
 40 &  4.01340 \\
 50 &  3.88654 \\
 60 &  3.78444 \\
 70 &  3.69954 \\
 80 &  3.62722 \\
 90 &  3.56446 \\
 100 &  3.50919 \\
 200 &  3.16830 \\
 300 &  2.98811 \\
 400 &  2.86885 \\
 500 &  2.78111 \\
 600 &  2.71240 \\
 700 &  2.65635 \\
 800 &  2.60925 \\
 900 &  2.56880 \\
 1000 &  2.53346
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $1\leq n \leq 100$, it seems that an approximate model such as
$$x_n=\frac{1}{2 W\left(\frac{1}{8 \sqrt[4]{e}}\right)}-\frac {a n^b} {1+c n^b}$$ could be reasonable. A quick and dirty regression gives $(R^2=0.999997)$

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.173767 & 0.001858 & \{0.170078,0.177455\} \\
 b & 0.060416 & 0.000426 & \{0.059571,0.061262\} \\
 c & 0.823962 & 0.004616 & \{0.814799,0.833124\} \\
\end{array}$$